# How to change vagrant guest vm ip when the host machine changes the network?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a vagrant client box "ubuntu/trusty64" on my laptop.
I frequently change networks home/work/caffe or connect my laptop to my cell hotspot.

I would like to use public networking on all the different networks by re-configuring the network interface of vagrant client according to the network I have my machine in. So I'm not afraid to add routes or uncomment configuration blocks as needed - as long as it works.

I would like to also use the ssh config file on my ubuntu host machine so I could easily navigate the file system of the vagrant boxes via sftp.

**Question**: how should I do it.

This is what I have tried:

```
The initial setup that works:

Host machine:
---------------
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

...
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether a4:c4:94:5f:00:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a6c4:94ff:fe5f:a5/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Guest vm:
---------------
config.vm.network :public_network, bridge: "wlan0", ip: "192.168.1.251", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
```

Then I change the network (for example connect to the cell hotspot):

```
Host machine:
---------------
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.43.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether a4:c4:94:5f:00:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.43.101/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a6c4:94ff:fe5f:a5/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



Guest vm:
---------------
config.vm.network :public_network, bridge: "wlan0", ip: "192.168.43.105", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
```

Connecting to 192.168.43.105 does not work via ssh (by using ssh config). After investigating I see that the network interface is not even assigned (I saw this by checking the GUI in virtual box during startup):

[image]

The OLD ip is getting assigned.

Let me know on any thoughts and ideas for troubleshooting.

P.S.

I'm moving the question from serverfault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/798980/how-to-change-vagrant-guest-vm-ip-when-the-host-machine-changes-the-network

Sorry in advance if this is not according to he rules. I really hope it is.

Comment: Would assigning an IP alias on the machine solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this, but all of them involve either the host or the guess machine participating in the same network.

I simply created an ip alias on my network-manager managed wlan0 connection on my home and work network (a network is defined by IP and the subnet mask).

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether a4:c4:94:5f:00:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.0.158/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a6c4:94ff:fe5f:a5/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And the guess OS has just 1 IP:

```
config.vm.network :public_network, bridge: "wlan0", ip: "192.168.0.159", netmask: "255.255.255.0"
```

So now when I'm home I can ssh to the machine, since I have an IP alias and my NIC is participating in the same network as the guest machine. When I'm at work it will work automatically since my NIC will automatically be in the same subnet.